# Item not centered in Firefox when using writing-mode: vertical-rl; and flexbox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I want to use flexbox to put an text element on the center of screen.
It works perfectly with the default `writing-mode`, however, if `writing-mode` is changed to `vertical-rl` Firefox stretches the element to 100% of screen which means it cannot be centered anymore. The width of this text is dynamic, so I can't set a absolute width on this element. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```css
.vtext {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:center;">
  <div class="vtext">
    123
    <br>456
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "writing-mode: vertical-rl" is for CJK, not just rotate 90 degree.

Comment: Don't think this should be closed as a duplicate. @EricChang is not asking how to change the direction of the text but why Firefox is behaving in a particular manner when `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` is used in conjunction with flexbox.